# Facebook possibility to use one like button counter with different urls

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, google-plus

I want to share url: http://example.com/2, but need the like counter always to be on http://example.com/1

For example now in Twitter I am using data-counturl parameter

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo $twitter_url; ?>" data-counturl="<?php echo $share_url; ?>" data-count="vertical">Share</a>
```

So how you see in the code example I am using one url as data-url and counter is on another url. This is required to have for me, because an account is assigned with shortened URL to keep track of specific user and data information.

How can this be done with facebook (google+, linkedin)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell being able to target two different URLs, one for the count and one for the content that is shared, is unique to the twitter button. Facebook, Google+ and LinkedIn all require the same target for the count as the content that is shared.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood my question, I know how to specify a different URL than it is on the page for sharing, but how to specify a different data-counturl (see twitter code example) to have different links, but one counter.